# On hover child image slightly move to right

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have giving `transform:scale(0.95)` and on hover I am making `transform: scale(1)` just to give hover effect bounce out.
I have `img` as child. On Hover it will slightly move to right. I am using `backface-visibility: hidden` to avoid that issue but somehow it is not working for me.

#### [Link on which I am working](http://nalie.royaltri.com/)

After **About Me** 4 columns title and icons. (HEALTH & HEALING, INSPIRATION...)

I have also tried other technique like `will-change: transform` `transform: rotate(0)` etc. But nothing is working from me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use `transform: translate();` to compensate for the number of pixels it will move to the right.
for more info on transform translate, you can look at the following link.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate

Comment: I think it is not required because img is moving slightly on hover and then came back to its original place.

Comment: And you cant add translateX on hover to compensate for the movement?